# Undefined value on id with jQuery on elements created inside Knockout foreach

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I want to access an element `id` in jQuery function, but it returns undefined.

My HTML code is:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: showAds">
    <div data-bind="attr:{'id':id}"> //how to access this id in addcomment function
        <div>..other stuff..</div>

        <textarea placeholder="comment.." data-bind="value:newComment"></textarea>
        <input type="button" data-url="/api/comment" data-bind="click: addcomment" value="submit" />

        <div data-bind="foreach:showComment">
            <div data-bind="attr:{'id':id}"> //how to access this id in addcommentreply function.
                <div>.. show comment..</div>
                <textarea data-bind="value:newCommentReply" placeholder="reply.."></textarea>
                <input type="button" data-url="/api/comment" data-bind="click: addCommentReply" value="submit" />

                <div data-bind="foreach: showCommentReply">
                    <div data-bind="attr:{'id':id}">
                        <div>.. show comment reply .. </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js code is :

```
function commentReply(data) {
        var self = this;
        data = data || {};
        //other stuff
        self.id = data.id;
    }
function comment(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.id = data.id;
        //other stuff
        self.addCommentReply = function () {
            var commentId = $(this).parent().attr("id"); //shows undefined
            //send ajax reqest to post comment reply
        }
    }
function ad(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.id = data.id;
        //other sutff
        self.addcomment = function () {
            var = $(this).parent().attr('id'); //shows undefined
            //send ajax request to post comment
        }
    }
        function viewModel() {
                var self = this;
                self.showAds = ko.observableArray();
                self.loadad = function () {
                    //load ads using ajax
                }
                self.loadad();
                return self;
            }
    $(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
        });
```

How can I access `id`?

Comment: What does "its not working" mean? Please include enough (but *as little as possible*!) code to actually reproduce the issue. There's currently a lot of code in your question that is probably *not* needed to repro, and certainly some code missing that we *do* need to repro.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if that helps. You have not trimmed the HTML to only the relevant bits, added a function that is not bound to anywhere in that html, and not added enough relevant Javascript to reproduce the issue. Please check out [this advice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: well thanks for -1 hope this could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mix Knockout and jQuery in that way. Instead, avoid using jQuery for logic, and try not to use information from the DOM inside your view models.

If you need to make sub-viewmodels aware of their parent attributes, there are multiple ways to do this. For example you could use Knockout contexts on click events:

```js
function CommentReply(data) {
  var self = this;
}

function Comment(data){
  var self = this;
  self.txt = ko.observable();
  self.isEditing = ko.observable(!data || !data.id);
}

function Ad(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.txt = ko.observable(data.txt);
  self.comments = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  self.addComment = function() {
    self.comments.push(new Comment());
  }
  
  self.saveComment = function(comment) {
    console.log(self); // id accessible here
    console.log(comment); // id accessible here
    comment.isEditing(false);
  }
}

function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;  
  self.ads = ko.observableArray([]);
  
  self.loadAds = function() {
    // Normally loading with Ajax, but stubbing it here:
    self.ads.push(new Ad({ id: 1, txt: "Buy shampoo now!" }));
    self.ads.push(new Ad({ id: 2, txt: "Best pizza in town.!" }));
  }
  
  self.loadAds();
}

$(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
});
```

```css
.ad { padding: 10px; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: ads">
  <div class="ad">
    <div data-bind="text: txt"></div> 
    <input type="button" data-bind="click: addComment" value="add comment" />
    <div data-bind="foreach: comments">
      <p data-bind="text: txt, visible: !isEditing()"></p>
      <div data-bind="visible: isEditing">
        <textarea data-bind="value: txt"></textarea>
        <input type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.saveComment" value="save comment">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This example can easily be extended to one extra level of nesting with "comment replies".

There are several variations that are suited for different tastes, including:

- Placing DAL-type methods on `$root`, and passing the appropriate variables (like `$data` and `$parent` or even `$parents[1]`) to it.
- Making your view model constructors dependent on their parent, e.g. asking for the `Ad` when constructing a `Comment`, so your `click` handlers can navigate up the tree if they have to.

You should probably go through Knockout's tutorials (the ones on the website itself), and/or read [the Binding context documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html).